# Macro for Creating a outlook calendar event from 1 cell value in excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I am very new to macros/VBA and am struggling with getting something set up on excel to send a calendar event to my outlook for a month before the date in a cell value.

Basically, I have to send a yearly document and am terrible at remembering when its due so was hoping i could set up something in excel that then put the date - 30 days in my calendar so i have time to edit the document with new dates and then send on.

I have found a script that pdfs/sends to outlook email the document and pulls through the email address etc but i can't figure out how to add a calendar event/reminder for the next time.

Any help for a newbie would be really appreciated

i can't find anything remotely looking like what i need so am completely stumped!

Comment: If it's only yearly why not manually put a recurring reminder in outlook for a month before the due date?

Comment: If you were searching for how to create an "event", try searching instead for how to create an "appointment" or "meeting": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814610/creating-outlook-appointment-from-excel-data-with-vba.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a VB or a macro as it can get complicated quite quickly. I would use power automate if done regularly or a direct import if done on an ad-hoc basis as they are both easier and quicker then writing a VB code

Power automate (video is very quiet)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9uJ4vLx-Xg

Direct import
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-import-excel-records-into-an-outlook-calendar/